# How to hide FaceTime audio macOS High Sierra Version 10.13

Tags: macos, high-sierra, software, facetime

Is it possible to hide FaceTime audio?

It certainly was possible to hide or move the window in earlier macOS versions but with macOS High Sierra I can't select the window nor can I hide it with shortcuts.

[image: new FaceTime]

The old version:

[image]

The position in the top left corner is very annoying and sometimes I have to resize windows to click on something (for example Safari buttons).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This seems like a bug.

Also other people had this kind of question too: [Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8095870)

I have found three temporary workarounds (the last one is the best). All of them force quit the process `FaceTimeNotificationCenterService`:

- Open **Activity Monitor** and search for `FaceTime`. Then select `FaceTimeNotificationCenterService`, press the red circled button and choose `Force Quit`.

  [image]
- Open **Terminal** and type `killall -kill FaceTimeNotificationCenterService` then press <kbd>return</kbd> (⮐)

  With this command you essentially `Force Quit` the process. (For more information type `man killall`; `-kill` sends the signal `kill` instead of the default signal `term` to the process)
- For a more permanent solution you start **Automator** make a new `Application`. Here you go to `Utilities` and drag `Run Shell Script` to your workflow. Write `killall -kill FaceTimeNotificationCenterService` in the text field and you can save the document.

  [image]

  As a shortcut you can place this `Application` in your dock so it needs only single click to activate.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: Towards the end of the discussion you linked to someone suggested: "open the notification centre from the side and turn on " do not disturb""

Comment: @MarcelStör Thank you very much! I will try it out and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarcelStör I'm on macOS 10.14.6 and the window **does not disappear** if I turn on "do not disturb". (I tried turning it on/off before and also during the call)

Comment: How do I bring the facetime app back after killing that process? Do I have to kill facetime all together and then start it again?

Comment: @eyal83 Unfortunately yes, you have to quit and restart FaceTime.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I created a small app that you can run after you have your facetime call going that will hide the window. http://onetoshare.com/AH2Bjq

Comment: Thanks! was a little nervous to "try out", but your little app works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the notification via System Preferences > Notifications > Facetime by unticking "Badge app icon".

I do appreciate the notification to answer the call. Even though my MacBook has a touch bar which also allows me to Answer/End, Video or Mute. Also note the touch bar doesn't sport the button you need when you have to dial during a call ("Select 1 for department A, Select 2 for department B"). So, you'll need the pop-up.

Don't forget to provide Apple feedback on this. Even though it's been a few years, hopefully they'll find a better solution than the current notification.
https://www.apple.com/feedback/macbook.html