# Hiding/Unhiding FaceTime audio window macOS High Sierra Version 10.13

Tags: macos, high-sierra, software, facetime

I created an Automator app to hide the window during a call following these instructions:

[How to hide FaceTime audio macOS High Sierra Version 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313717/how-to-hide-facetime-audio-macos-high-sierra-version-10-13)

But is there a way to bring the window back as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to restart your computer.

Comment: I can end the call by quitting Facetime and the next time I make or receive a call, the window comes back.  I'm talking about bringing the window back DURING a call after I've executed the Automator app to hide the window in the first place.

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: @BSO I think this isn't possible since your Automator app stops the FaceTime notification process.